# ansible-playbook: ERROR: provided hosts list is empty

Tags: ansible

When I run `ansible-playbook web_db.yaml` I get

```
ERROR: provided hosts list is empty
```

Any idea why?

Some additional information:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 100 Aug  4 14:55 ansible.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 222 Oct 20  2016 inventory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 531 May  3 11:58 web_db.yaml

$ pwd
/home/vagrant/exercise1/production

$ cat inventory 
web1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.33.20
[webservers]
web1

$ cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]

inventory      = /home/vagrant/exercise1/production/inventory
host_key_checking = False

$ ansible --version
ansible 1.5.4

$ cat web_db.yaml 
---
- hosts: webservers
  sudo: yes
```

Comment: Your ansible version is really old...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, that ancient Ansible versions used [hostfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#hostfile) parameter instead of `inventory`.

Try with

```
hostfile = /home/vagrant/exercise1/production/inventory
```

in your config.

Comment: I had the same problem. This user is following a course online from pluralsight. Adding hostfile worked for me and I am using Ansible version 1.5.4 as well